# Firebase is not defined in Electron main process

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, electron

I have defined Firebase in the HTML file in Renderer process. How can I use it in the Electron Main process files?

Comment: maybe check https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-firebase-in-electron-tips-and-tricks-24ac5b44bf5a

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample code also?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but maybe there is a better way to do it. 
I have used Electron's IPC (inter process communication) modules, ipcMain, ipcRenderer and webContents to communicate between the two processes, and defined and use Firebase only in one module (in my case renderer).